# Delete Network Interface MacOS Sonoma

Tags: virtual-machine, macos

Recently I was playing with UTM and VMware Fusion on my Mac to try to create some virtual machines on an apple new processors, I have a Macbook Air M2, and I uninstalled UTM and Fusion from my Mac using an App Cleaner and Uninstalling, but, I see a lot of network interfaces that cannot be deleted from the uninstalling process.

```
➜  ~ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384

gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
anpi0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

anpi1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

en3: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

en4: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

ap1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

awdl0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000

utun2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1000

utun3: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
```

Any idea of how to delete them and have network configuration as a default ?.

Regards,